# How do Transfer Protocols work?

Tags: protocols

Hypothetically, lets say that I wanted to study/create (a) transfer protocol such as http, ftp or ptp. How would I go about doing so? What do I need to know about the internet and servers and what do I need to make to be able to send and receive data through my own homemade transfer protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a little backwards.

First you have a problem you need to solve that involves multiple machines.

Then you write software to solve it, which requires communication between those machines.

The details of that communication is called a 'protocol'.

Since the protocol is the interface between machines, it's beneficial if it is generic enough to let you swap out the software on one side or the other.

In this way, HTTP was invented to serve web pages to browsers, FTP was invented to let users transfer files, etc.  The details of the protocol indicate the elements of communication required to solve the problem in the desired way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess now I'm a bit smarter :)